# What are all the passive weapon effects in COD: Cold War (Zombies)?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-cold-war

I noticed that some weapons have a passive effect when you Pack-a-Punch them. For instance, the Gallo shotgun has an explosive ammo effect which sometimes triggers on melee.

**What are all the weapons that gain an effect besides increased ammo / damage when Pack-a-Punched (and what is that effect?)**

I could not find a list on the wiki, and a lot of results returned are for earlier COD titles (at least at this point). There were weapons in other Black Ops titles that changed drastically when you PaP'ed them, most notably the ballistic knife and the crossbow, so I was curious if there was anything along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

The ballistic knife changes drastically when Pack-a-Punched: if you shoot someone while they’re down they will get revived

The starting M1911 handgun will  become duel-wielded and fire rifle grenades - making it similar the game's "Death Machine" - when upgraded

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This answer is currently very basic and lacking of description and detail. We expect answers to be of quality on our network, so you need to add sources, back up your claims, and talk more about what each thing does, instead of giving an incomplete solution (without explicitly stating it). Show that you're putting effort into giving answers here, that's what we're all about.